# Stash and Expresso Store modifiers

Tags: expresso-store, stash

I'm trying to use stash withing Expresso Store modifiers

```
 {exp:stash:set_list name="price_list"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
    {modifiers}
        {modifier_options}
            {if price_mod_val}{stash:item_price}{price_mod_val}{/stash:item_price}{/if}
        {/modifier_options}
    {/modifiers}
 {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

but unfortunately I'm getting item_price as {price_mod_val} text instead price value

What kind of tags order suppose to be in that case?

Thanks

Comment: So you want the formatted value instead of unformatted? If so then use `{price_mod}` instead of `{price_mod_val}`.

Comment: Well - my issue is that `{price_mod_val}` tag is not translated - just comes as is as a string/text :)

Comment: Ah I see. In that case I'd probably look to move the Stash `stash:set_list` tag inside of the `store:product` tag and then add `parse_depth="3"`.

Comment: OK. Got it to work. Answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ian to put me on proper path to solve my issue. Working code below:

```
 {exp:stash:set_list name="price_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3" parse_conditionals="yes"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
    {modifiers}
        {modifier_options}
            {if price_mod_val}{stash:item_price}{price_mod_val}{/stash:item_price}{/if}
        {/modifier_options}
    {/modifiers}
 {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```